# What episode does this particular scene with a Takoyaki "song" occur?

Tags: one-piece, music

I'm looking for the scene where Luffy, Usopp and Chopper (maybe someone else too, I don't remember) are singing 'Ta-ko-ya-ki, Tak-ko-ya-ki" and so on, and so on.

I thought it was around the time Hachi was kidnapped by the Flying Fish Riders but Google doesn't give me any relevant results. I do remember that there was another scene about Takoyaki, back in Going Merry times, but I don't know anything more specific about that part.

If someone would be able to tell me what episode this scene is from I would be so happy :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Episode 145 has them eating takoyaki but I don't remember if they can't it

Comment: Just had a look at episodes 145 and 390, the two times I know they ate takoyaki - neither one has them singing about it.

Comment: @Ananisapta Thank you for the effort :) I'll look a bit around myself over the weekend but I don't have much time atm.. I'm sure they sing about it sometime in the show because a friend of mine and me sing it from time to time because it was funny xD

Comment: @Gravinco - It's quite frustrating - I've found several different scenes where Luffy *is* singing, but not once about takoyaki.

Comment: @Ananisapta I know right.. I had the same problem, Google doesn't give me the response I want and I haven't been able to check episodes anymore :-/

Comment: Wasn't he singing in the forest in skypiea?

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why hasn't anyone added a music tag to the question?

Comment: @RichardThomas feel free to do so yourself nest time, if you feel that the tag is relevant to the question

Comment: @Jens Indeed he was singing there but it was a completely different song. I believe it was about islands in the north, south, .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckAlXg-2T5I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to [this](https://youtu.be/a0IF0KoWJ6Y?t=9m32s) short gag in **Episode 386** when Luffy & Co. decide to save Hatchan so that they can get free Takoyaki.

Comment: That's a short version of what I was looking for but it'll do :) thanks a lot!